# How do I do bit operations on a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, bit-manipulation, conversion-operator

I have a bitfield struct on which I want to perform bitwise operations using masks.
I want to know the simplest and most efficient way to do this.
I have tried using my conversion operator (which seems an inefficient way of doing the & operation on two structs) but I get error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const test::dtType' to 'char'. No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

```
class test
{
   public:
    test() : startTime(0), endTime(5,23) {}
    ~test();

    struct dtType {
        // inline constructors with initialisation lists
        dtType() {dtType(0);}
        dtType(byte z) {dtType(z,z);}
        dtType(byte n,byte h) : mins(n), hrs(h){}

        // inline overloaded operator functions
        operator char() {return mins + hrs<<3;}; // allow casting the struct as a char

        // All I want to do is return (this & hrsMask == date & hrsMask)
        // I know that in this trivial case I can do return (hrs == date.hrs) but I have simplified it for this example.
        bool operator== (dtType date){return (char(this) & char(hrsMask)) == (char(date) & char(hrsMask));};

        // data members
        unsigned mins: 3; // 10's of mins
        unsigned hrs: 5; // 8 bits
    };
    const static dtType hrsMask; // initialised outside the declaraion, since a static is not associated with an individual object.
    dtType startTime; // initialised by test() in its initialisation list
    dtType endTime; // initialised by test() in its initialisation list
};

// Typically in a source file, but can be in the header.
const test::dtType hrsMask(0,31);
```

I have tried using void pointers to do the bitwise operation. It compiles, but I haven't tested it.

```
bool test::dtType::operator== (dtType date){
    const void * longThisDT = this;
    const void * longThatDT = & date;
    const void * longMaskDT = & hrsMask;
    return (*((long *)longThisDT) &  *((long *)longMaskDT) == *((long *)longThatDT) &  *((long *)longMaskDT));
};
```

Is this about as efficient as we can get? It involves three extra pointers, when all I really need is a cast to long.

Comment: I usually use unions and/or bitfields for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I started off with a union, but you can't have a union containing a struct with non-trivial constructors.

Comment: And a union with something containing bit fields doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @James: Why not use a union with a bitfield? I use the bitfield for manipulation and a long in the union to store the bitfield to EEPROM.

Comment: @StephenD If it's totally local, it will work, but why not store the struct with the bitfields itself.  The usual use of the union with a bitfield is to match some external layout, however, and this doesn't work, since the layout of a bitfield is not specified, and can vary between implementations.

Answer (score 0):

first of all take your time to prepare WORKING example, yours has many errors:
- no ~test defined
- *const test::dtType hrsMask(0,31);* is incorrect, should be: *const test::dtType test:hrsMask(0,31);*

other then that:
- you should change *operator char() {* to *operator char() const {* - that's what compiler whine exactly about :)
- shouldn't there be *byte mins: 3* instead of *unsigned mins: 3* which really means 'unsigned int' so that uses 4 bytes anyway

Comment: `unsigned mins : 3;` means 3 bits, somewhere in a larger element.  (Where, and the type of the larger element, are implementation defined.)

Comment: yeah but is sample we received only 'unsigned' was with 2 elements, so that means 'unsigned int' for compiler, that's what I meant

Comment: The example I posted compiles fine without the operator= line.
This is for an 8-bit micro controller and I have only shown part of the whole bitfield.
According to my c++ book, unsigned is all I need to define unsigned bits in a bitfield.
Thanks. Making the operator char() const does indeed work.
But is there a more efficient way of doing bitwise operations on a bitfield?

Comment: @zodi I'm not sure what you're talking about.  The code I saw had `unsigned mins : 3;`, which defines an element of three bits.

Comment: @James: yeah, 3 bits, but taken from what data type? In this case from 'unsigned int' which is still 4 bytes, 32 bits long (in most cases). Not big concern as StephenD pointed - that's just part of his code.

Comment: @James: When I do sizof() I get 1 byte for my bitfield, not 4 bytes as ypu suggest.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way of doing bitwise operations on a bitfield?

Comment: @zodi The underlying type is implementation defined, but since he only uses 8 bits in the entire `struct`, from a quality of implementation point of view, it shouldn't be more than 8 bits.  As for the declaration of the bitfield, if the number of bits is less than 8, whether you say `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int` or even `unsigned long` makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It works when `this` is indirected and consts are removed:

```
bool operator== (dtType date) {
    return (char(*this) & char(hrsMask)) == (char(date) & char(hrsMask));};

/* ... */

static dtType hrsMask;

/* ... */

 test::dtType test::hrsMask(0,31);
```

Comment: James and Zodi are arguing about bitfield types and ignoring my question. Do you know of a more efficient way of doing bitwise operations on a bitfield. Since I have non-trivial constructors I can't use a union. What about a void pointer?? I've never had to use one before. I just need to get the compiler to let me treat the bitfield as a long. Any ideas?